# To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.(Entity Framework Core 5.0. 2)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In  my recent project I am using version Entity Framework Core 5.0. 2. I have created my project using code first approach.

Database - sql server 2016

I am able to create the database using command "Update-Database". But I am facing the issue when I am adding any new column in my model and then trying to update.  Below is the error message

```
System.InvalidOperationException: To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(AlterColumnOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.<>c.<.cctor>b__83_4(MigrationsSqlGenerator g, MigrationOperation o, IModel m, MigrationCommandListBuilder b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass16_2.<GetMigrationCommandLists>b__2()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.
```

Comment: Looks like you're doing something to the PK field which will have to be dropped and recreated in code-first. If you don't want to drop it, make the change in Mgmt Studio then make the change in your model. Comment out the code in the migration and update the db with the empty migration.

Comment: @GHDevOps, I am not  doing something to the PK field. I have just added a new column/field and getting this error.

Comment: You may be adding more than one migration. Can you post your up method from the migration?